# Why are my list and list items overlapping @page defined margins?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to debug generated CSS files. One of the generated CSS files prepares each page for PDF generation by setting the page margins and header and footer margins. In the CSS that defines the page, in this case a TOC page, the rule is:

```
@page procssv2contentssection {
    size: Letter portrait;
    margin-left: 1.9cm;
    margin-right: 1.9cm;
    margin-top: 1.9cm;
    margin-bottom: 1.27cm; 
    orphans: 4; widows:2;

    /* ContentsFooterODD */
    @bottom-left-corner {
        content: none;
        margin-bottom: 1.9cm;
        vertical-align: top;
        margin-top: -1.0099999999999997cm;
    }
    @bottom-left {
        content: element(BottomLeft);
        margin-bottom: 1.9cm;
        vertical-align: top;
        margin-top: -1.0099999999999997cm;
        border-top:    0.50pt solid #010101;
    }
    @bottom-center {
        content: element(BottomCenter);
        margin-bottom: 1.9cm;
        vertical-align: top;
        margin-top: -1.0099999999999997cm;
        border-top:    0.50pt solid #010101;
    }
    @bottom-right {
        content: element(BottomRight);
        margin-bottom: 1.9cm;
        vertical-align: top;
        margin-top: -1.0099999999999997cm;
        border-top:    0.50pt solid #010101;
    }
    @bottom-right-corner {
        content: none;
        margin-bottom: 1.9cm;
        vertical-align: top;
        margin-top: -1.0099999999999997cm;
    }
}
```

ul and li elements that fill this page, go outside of the bottom margins and over writer the footer. (Their style rules are in another CSS file.) The offending li item is:

```
<li class="h4 proceduretopic_onesite_">
                      <a class="title" href="#H129976">Resending an Invite</a>
                      <a class="pagenumber" href="#H129976"></a>
                    </li>
```

The rules for a are:

```
.tableofcontents .h4  a {
    color: black;
    font-weight: normal;
    font: 10.5pt segoeui;
    widows: 2; orphans: 2;
}
```

The style rule for this li element is:

```
ul.toc > li.h4 {
    margin-top: 3pt;
}
```

The last two list items overlay the footer information, before it continues to the next page. The CSS for the page layout it consistent for the other pages and those flow text fine.

Can anyone suggest ways I can fix this?

Thanks,

Russ

Comment: I'd usually work backwards in a case like this. Debug the generated CSS, then make changes to your pre-processed rules. You should really tag whatever that markup is.

Comment: AFAIK the generated CSS SHOULD be ok. The other pages it controls all look fine. The styles for the li and a elements are from the other CSS, if this is what you were referring to.